# Error: Type integral takes type parameters ...... Scala

Tags: scala

I wrote a code in scala with many functions however when i run the code , in one function i get 3 errors :

1)type Integral takes type parameters
 def date(start_date:String,end_date:String,duration:Integral,final_list:List[List[List[String]]]):List[List[List[List[String]]]]=

2)type List takes type parameters
        failed_list_with_date::=ListList[List]

3)type List takes type parameters
        failed_list_with_date::=ListList[List]

here are the related excerpts from the code

```
def **joda_to_string(time:org.joda.time.DateTime):String**=
{
  val datestring= time.getYearOfEra.toString+"-"+time.getMonthOfYear.toString+"-"+  time.getDayOfMonth.toString
  return datestring
}

def date(start_date:String,end_date:String,**duration:Integral**,final_list:List[List[List[String]]  ]):List[List[List[List[String]]]]=
{

var failed_list_with_date=List[List[List[List[String]]]]()
var start_list=(start_date.split("-"))
var end_list=end_date.split("-")
val start_date_strip=new DateTime((start_list(0).toInt), start_list(1).toInt,   start_list(2).toInt,0,0,0,0)
val end_date_strip=new DateTime((end_list(0).toInt), end_list(1).toInt,   end_list(2).toInt,0,0,0,0)
var diff=((end_date_strip.getMillis-start_date_strip.getMillis)/3600/1000/24)
  **var a = start_date_strip
var b =a.plusDays(duration).minusDays(1)**
if (failed_list==List[List[List[String]]]()){}
  else
  {
    **failed_list_with_date::=List[List[List]](joda_to_string(b))
    failed_list_with_date::=List[List[List]](joda_to_string(a))**
```

I know it looks confusing i tried to post the necessary parts of code and put the important things between **

Comment: The first thing would be to format your question in a readable manner (put the exact error messages; indent and line break the source code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that's a confusing question.

Lets start with some reformatting. Also a style note, in Scala you often don't need to use the `return` keyword. Any code block will return the value of its last expression. Also, Scala will automatically call `toString` on the non-String objects as it builds the result String using `+`:

```
def joda_to_string( time: org.joda.time.DateTime ): String = {
  time.getYearOfEra.toString + "-" + time.getMonthOfYear +
    "-" + time.getDayOfMonth
}

def date( start_date: String, end_date: String, duration: Int,
          final_list: List[List[List[String]]] ): List[List[List[List[String]]]] = {

    var failed_list_with_date = List[List[List[List[String]]]]()
    var start_list = (start_date.split("-"))
    var end_list = end_date.split("-")
    val start_date_strip = new DateTime((start_list(0).toInt), start_list(1).toInt,   start_list(2).toInt,0,0,0,0)
    val end_date_strip = new DateTime((end_list(0).toInt), end_list(1).toInt,   end_list(2).toInt,0,0,0,0)
    var diff=((end_date_strip.getMillis-start_date_strip.getMillis)/3600/1000/24)
      var a = start_date_strip
    var b = a.plusDays(duration).minusDays(1)
    if (failed_list == List[List[List[String]]]()) {}
      else {
    failed_list_with_date ::= List(List(List(joda_to_string(b))))
    failed_list_with_date ::= List(List(List(joda_to_string(a))))
    }
  }
```

The errors are actually quite straight forward, if you know what a type parameter is. The first one is `type Integral takes type parameters`. This is because you have used the wrong type. You probably meant `Int`, which is Scala's version of `Integer`.

The other two remind you that `List takes a type parameter`. You have a nested type: `List[List[List]]` 
Well the inner type here is a `List` and ... it needs a type parameter. Perhaps you meant `List[List[List[String]]]`? Actually, you need to construct a list of the appropriate type here, which is what: `List(List(List(joda_to_string(b))))` does.

But I really don't know because this is the weirdest ass type I have ever seen.

Without trying to figure out what your code is trying to do (because it makes my head hurt), my guess is that you should really be using a plain `List[String]` and you should be prepending the new element to the front of the list each time:

```
failed_list_with_date ::= joda_to_string(b)
```